# Smooth Map $f: S^k \to \mathbb{R}^n$ Extends to the Disc

Tags: differential-topology

I am helping some students study for an exam. We have a two part problem. The first part is to prove that any smooth map $f: S^k \to \mathbb{R}^n$ extends to a smooth map $F: D^{k + 1} \to \mathbb{R}^n$. We tried to define 
$$
F(x) := |x|f\left( \frac{x}{|x|} \right)
$$
and $F(0) := 0$. This is certainly continuous. But, we couldn't show that it is smooth. Is this the correct map?

The second part of the problem says, if $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a closed manifold of dimension $m$ such that $k + 1 < n - m$, then any smooth map $S^k \to \mathbb{R}^n - M$ extends to a smooth map $D^{k + 1} \to \mathbb{R}^n - M$. I thought maybe I could use the dimension condition to get that the image is contractible, and use some version of the first part. But, that's all I've got.

I should mention that the class is just a graduate introduction course. So, they've got the basics of manifolds, Sard's Theorem, etc. No Morse Theory though.

Comment: I don't know if your $F$ is smooth, but if it's not then I'll bet that $|x|^2f(x/|x|)$ is.

Comment: Why don't you use that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible? Any linear homotopy from such $f$ to a point in its image will be smooth and will provide such an extension. That is for the first part.

Comment: The second part implies that $\pi_k(\mathbb{R}^n-M)=0$ for all those $k$. So maybe that is something you could start with. It seems trickier, though.

Comment: I'm confused. For the second part, does the extended map have range $\Bbb R^n$ or $\Bbb R^n-M$? It seems to me that, as written, the problem requires no hypotheses other than to apply the first part directly.

Comment: @Laz Their class did not cover higher homotopy groups.  So, I think that's not a fair approach.  Though it does seem promising.

Comment: @TedShifrin It should be $\mathbb{R}^n - M$.  I have corrected it.

Comment: OK, Joe. I just said "homotopy" because that is it's name, but you don't have to mention that word if you want.

Comment: Hmm, if we had $k+1<m$ we could do it by the transversality extension theorem (since the map is transverse to $M$ by default on the boundary), extending as a map to $\Bbb R^n$ and then wiggling to make it transverse to $M$. The $n-m$ suggests that we should be thinking about deforming the given smooth map into a fiber of the normal bundle of $M$.

Answer (score 2):

Given an application $f : \mathbb{S}^{k} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$, define its radial extension by $F : \mathbb{R}^{k+1} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$, with : $F(x) = |x|.f \left(\dfrac{x}{|x|} \right)$ if $x \neq 0$ and $F(0) = 0$.

Then, $F$ is differentiable at the point $0 \in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ if, and only if, $f$ is (the restriction to $\mathbb{S}^{k}$) of a linear transformation.

Indeed, by definition of $F$, we have: $\dfrac{F \left(tx \right)}{t}$, if $ t > 0$ and $\dfrac{F \left(tx \right)}{t} = - F(-x)$, if $t < 0$.

As $F(0) = 0$, suppose $F$ differentiable at point $x = 0$, there exists $\displaystyle  \lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{F \left(tx \right)}{t}$. Therefore $F(x) = - F(-x)$. $$F(x) = \displaystyle  \lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{F \left(tx \right)}{t} = F'(0).x$$

therefore, F coincides with the linear transformation $F'(0) : \mathbb{R}^{k+1} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$. The reciprocal is true.

Comment: So basically you are saying that the OP's suggested map is not smooth in general...

Comment: Right. I just wanted to help understand the differentiability at the origin.